# Databricks Apache Spark HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I tried to download an image with Databricks on Apache Spark using wget but got an error like the following:

```
%sh
wget https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.apache.org/kafka/2.7.0/kafka_2.13-2.7.0.tgz

--2022-03-16 20:06:17--  https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.apache.org/kafka/2.7.0/kafka_2.13-2.7.0.tgz
Resolving www.mirrorservice.org (www.mirrorservice.org)... 212.219.56.184, 2001:630:341:12::184
Connecting to www.mirrorservice.org (www.mirrorservice.org)|212.219.56.184|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-03-16 20:06:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look onto level higher (https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.apache.org/kafka/) you will see that this mirror doesn't have 2.7.0 - it's a common practice to mirror only few latest versions, not all of them. If you need this old version, you need to use main Apache archive

Comment: Hi Alex, you're 100% correct. Thanks